# Create and write excel file using PHP

Tags: php

```
 fputcsv($fp, $fields[0]);
```

It returns : *fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in ....*

Where as my array is : Array ( [0] => Murshidabad [value] => Murshidabad ) ....

My question is in PHP how to write values in excel row wise(ie new row but same column entry is rqrd).

My code snippet was :

```
$list = mysql_fetch_array($result);
foreach($list as $arr){
        fputcsv($fp,  $list ,"\r\n");
}
```

Comment: Just remove the [0] from the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     fputcsv($fp, $list);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example

```
$list = array (
array('#', 'Registrar', 'Country', 'Website', 'Email Address'),
array('123', '456', '789', 'aaa', 'bbb'),
array('123', '456', '789', 'aaa', 'bbb'),
);

$fp = fopen('registrars.xls', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
fputcsv($fp, $fields, "\t", '"');
}

fclose($fp);
```

Or you can use http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

The optional **delimiter** parameter sets the field delimiter (one character only).

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

Working code snippet is :

```
$fp = fopen(time().'.xls', 'w');
    $sql = "<your query here>";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($modelRow =mysql_fetch_row($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $val = $modelRow[$fieldname];
        fwrite($fp, "\"{$val}\"\r\n"); 
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use $list in *fputcsv* is that right?
Try this one:

```
$list = mysql_fetch_array($result);
foreach($list as $arr){
        fputcsv($fp,  $arr,"\n");
}
```

And the delimiter should be only one character.

Answer (score 0):

WriteExcel.php code follows:

```
$info=$_POST['info'];

$fp = fopen('sample.xls', 'w');

foreach ($info as $fields) {
     fputcsv($fp, $fields, "\t", '"');
}

fclose($fp);
```

The above PHP file can be called fom JavaScript using AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {info:info},
   url: "WriteExcel.php",
   success: function(msg){
       alert(msg);
    }
});
```